# Maven: Is it posible to prompt for proxy passwords instead?

Tags: maven, proxy

I know that there is the Maven Proxy settings according to its guide : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html .

However, in my company, the password is for personal use and I wouldn't like to expose it in plain text inside a file for a number of reasons.

Is there a way to prompt the user for the password? Or maybe any other solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not using a repository manager ?

Comment: No. Actually, I don't know very much about Maven. I tried to use it, but I came across this obstacle and gave up - now I came back with the idea again. But,  I think I'm starting to understand by what you asked me. I'll keep a repository behind the proxy so my team can automatically build maven without connecting do internet. Is that it?

Comment: Yes this is the idea behind it. Using a repository manager is really a good idea. Using Nexus OSS or Artifactory OSS ....

Comment: All right! Guess that is in fact an answer to the question! Thanks!